# How to merge two ArrayAdapter<String> for one view?

Tags: java, arrays, list, view, adapter

I have this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> codeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.code, codes);
ArrayAdapter<String> dateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.date, dates);
```

I would like to have just one `ArrayAdapter` but is not possible cause I have two different `R.id.code` and `R.id.date`.

How can I resolve?

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom adapter with two view types and then pass one ArrayList with all values and a boolean value for checking which value is for which view .
In adapter check boolean and then set the value according to boolean value.
and it will need only one adapter also one ArrayList